# Erro ao fazer o build do app (cordova build android), após adicionar e configurar o "cordova-plugin-firebase"

Tags: android, apache-cordova, cordova-plugin, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Criei um App usando o Cordova, depois segui as instruções para preparar o App para integrar com o plugin do Firebase:**

1. Criei a keystore (necessária para integrar com o
   Firebase).
2. Depois criei o projeto do aplicativo no Firebase e informei o hash
   armazenado na keystore.
3. Então instalei o plugin `cordova-plugin-firebase`.
4. E copie o arquivo google-services.json para a pasta raiz do projeto.

**Depois de seguir a documentação do plugin e do Firebase, me deparei com esse erro:**

> :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > File google-services.json is
>   missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
>   Searched Location:
>   /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/src/nullnull/debug/google-services.json
>   /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/src/debug/nullnull/google-services.json
>   /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/src/nullnull/google-services.json
>   /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/src/debug/google-services.json
>   /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/src/nullnullDebug/google-services.json
>   /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/google-services.json

**Solução proposta aqui no SO:** copiar o `google-services.json` para o diretório `/platforms/android/app/`, mas isso gerou outro erro:

> :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
>   > [string/google_app_id] /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
>   >     [string/google_app_id]
>   >     /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml:
>   >     Error: Duplicate resources   [string/google_api_key]
>   >     /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml 
>   >     [string/google_api_key]
>   >     /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml:
>   >     Error: Duplicate resources

**PS:** Eu já tentei várias soluções propostas aqui no SO e nenhuma resolveu meu problema, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Encontrei uma solução para o problema:**

Instruções semelhantes às que eu segui (e que causaram o problema) estão disponíveis aqui, embora com as versões das dependências um pouco desatualizadas:

> [https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=pt-br)

O que causou o problema no meu caso foi seguir estas instruções na página de criação de aplicativos no Firebase e adicionar as dependências nos arquivos `build.gradle` do projeto e do módulo, como pode ser visto abaixo:

Adicionar arquivo `build.gradle` do projeto  `/project/platforms/android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter ()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        Google()
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // Firebase
        classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.0.0'
    }
}
```

E adicionar no arquivo `build.gradle` do módulo `/project/platforms/android/app/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral ()
        jcenter ()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        Google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // Firebase
        classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase: firebase-core: 16.0.0'
    }
}

// Firebase, add at the end of the same file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

**Solução:**

A solução que encontrei foi comentar as linhas precedidas pelo comentário `// Firebase`:

Arquivo `/project/platforms/android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter ()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        Google()
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // Firebase
        // classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.0.0'
    }
}
```

Arquivo `/project/platforms/android/app/build.gradle`:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral ()
            jcenter ()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
            Google()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

            // Firebase
            //classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.0.0'
            //classpath 'com.google.firebase: firebase-core: 16.0.0'
        }
    }

// Firebase, add at the end of the same file
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Após estes passos, tudo funcionou bem e eu pude rodar `$ cordova build android` sem problemas.

---

**Sugestão:**
Se ocorrer algum outro erro, tente remover os plug-ins e a plataforma e, em seguida, recrie-os:

```
$ cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase
$ cordova platform rm android

$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
$ cordova platform add android
```